# Dotted points not showing on list items

Tags: html, css

got a small problem, I added list-items inside a accordion and and the dotted points that should indicate the start of a item isn't showing up, any solution on how to fix this? And thanks for the help!

```
<section id="Specialist">
            <div class="services-container">
              <div class="left1">
                <div class="content">
                  <h1>Specialist  Services</h1>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et undevoluptatem</p>
                  <div class="accordion">
                    <div class="contentAB">
                      <div class="label">Specialist  Services</div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <ul>
                          <li>Fixed Term Contracts (Ad-Hoc).</li>
                          <li>Technical and project cost audits.</li>
                          <li>“Watching Brief” on EPCM and turnkey projects.</li>
                          <li>Mediation and dispute resolution.</li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="right1"></div>
            </div>
          </section>
```

Comment: These dots are disabled via CSS, you didn't post any CSS in your question. So we can't reproduce your problem. All we can tell you is: Open the dev tools and find out which rule disabled the CSS for the dots. Then remove said role (or use a second one with higher specifity to add the dots back in the accordion)

Comment: Thank you very much! I found the problem, turns out I had old redundant code that disabled it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.